# "Functional" way to get all list items inside a list

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

Basically, I have this piece of code:

```
    final List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

    feeds.forEach(feed -> articles.addAll(feed.getArticles()));

    return articles;
```

Is there a way to make it any more Java 8-functional? To eliminate the additional variable and make this entire block into a single return statement?

Comment: `return feeds.stream().flatMap(feed -> feed.getArticles().stream()).collect(toList());`

Comment: Do you mean something like that:`feeds.stream().map(Feed::getArticles).collect(Collectors.toList());` That is assuming that `feeds` is a collections of `Feed` objects.

Comment: @Michael It returns `List<List<Article>>`.

Comment: @saka1029 Right, missed the `.addAll`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes. Please add it as an answer below so that it can be more visible. :)

Comment: @Cube., the question has been marked as a duplicate; I can't add it as an answer, and it's not clear that I should when the duplicates are valid.